# Why does God test everyone differently?

Tags: allah

If this life is meant as a test for us humans, why does god test each one differently?

A baby who dies immediately after birth is guaranteed to go to heaven, while another person who lives till 80 may have to go through suffering of poverty, death of loved ones and risk sinning and going to hell.

How is this fair? Shouldn't all humans be tested equally? How can god send someone to heaven without having the chance to prove himself/herself by default?

Comment: Can you share the reference or source that states "A baby who dies immediately after birth is guaranteed to go to heaven" ?

Comment: So what will happen to someone who dies before they can live their life? Isn't killing them at birth violating free will, and a chance to do good deeds and go to heaven?

Comment: tbh, you stated that those who "die" as infants directly go to heaven. Hence, the onus is on the you to support the claim by references :) Also "killing/murder" is done by mortals. With reference to God, it is not a "Kill" but it was "His Will"

Comment: You still haven't answered my question, you're just pointing out grammatical errors. My point is, why are different individuals tested differently? Why do some people get easier tests while others more difficult ones? And why do some individuals die before they are given a chance to prove their worth on this Earth? (For example some babies who die of birth complications or genetic defects at birth).

Comment: I wasn't pointing out your grammatical errors, friend. There is a significant difference in semantics in your question and comments. But I will inshallah try to answer your question below to the best of my abilities.

Answer (score 1):

In [Surah Baqarah](https://quran.com/2/286), Allah says:

> **Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity.
> It will have [the consequence of] what [good] it has gained, and it
> will bear [the consequence of] what [evil] it has earned.** "Our Lord,
> do not impose blame upon us if we have forgotten or erred. Our Lord,
> and lay not upon us a burden like that which You laid upon those
> before us. Our Lord, and burden us not with that which we have no
> ability to bear. And pardon us; and forgive us; and have mercy upon
> us. You are our protector, so give us victory over the disbelieving
> people."

In another Hadith,

> Narrated Anas:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "**A Muslim whose three children die before the
> age of puberty will be granted Paradise** by Allah due to his mercy for
> them." 
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 1248](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1248)

and

> Aisha reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon
> him, said, “Be deliberate in worship, draw near to Allah, and give
> glad tidings. **Verily, none of you will enter Paradise because of his
> deeds alone**.” They said, “Not even you, O Messenger of Allah?” The
> Prophet said, “Not even me, unless Allah grants me mercy from himself.
> Know that the most beloved deed to Allah is that which is done
> regularly even if it is small.”
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 6099, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2818

From the above Hadiths, we can infer that no soul will be tested more than that they can endure. Secondly, no matter how many good deeds we earn, we will never be able to do justice to God. It is only through His Mercy alone that all of us, including Prophet Muhammed, will be granted Paradise.

Hence, those who did no sin inshallah will not be punished (dead toddlers as in your question, but perhaps through them their parents gain access to paradise) and those who do good deeds will have their ranks elevated in paradise.

Answer (score 0):

Islam is the religion of Justice, peace and equality.God sents his prophets to guide people what is right and what is wrong. Everything is very clear according to Hadith and holy Quran. People with knowledge and people without knowledge can never be equal.The same thing as you do will get the same result